# Manipulate following grammar to be LL(1)

Tags: parsing, grammar, ll-grammar

Suppose I was given the following grammar:

```
start -> statement //cannot change

statement ->  assignment SEMICOLON

statement ->  function_call SEMICOLON

assignment ->  IDENTIFIER EQUAL expression

function_call ->  IDENTIFIER LPAREN parameters RPAREN SEMICOLON
```

The grammar right now cannot be LL(1) because the non terminals for statement (assignment and function_call) both have IDENTIFIER as the first terminal for each of their production. Only through the use of 2 look aheads can you decide which path the parser will take.

Is there any way to manipulate the grammar above to be LL(1)? Or is it not possible?

Comment: Left-factoring should be easy to search for. Hint: `statement: IDENTIFIER rest; rest: something | something-else`

Comment: @rici I understand but if you had something like [statement -> compound_statement] and [compound_statement -> assignment | function_call] would that still be considered LL(1)?

Comment: no, it wouldn't. To be LL(1), you need to know which production will be expanded by looking at the next (1) tokens. The next token will be IDENTIFIER, and that will let you predict `statement -> compound_statement` but not which of the two `compound_statement` productions. So you need to left-factor or choose a more powerful parsing algorithm like LR(1).

Comment: @rici I just have one more question, can you please answer it. Is my grammar LL(K)? Does LL(K) grammar fit LL(1) grammar? Its been confusing me for a while if LL1() belongs in the subset for LL(K)

Comment: it is LL(2) because you can make the decision based on the next (2) tokens. Yes, LL(k) is a subset of LL(k') if k <= k'.

Answer (score 0):

The grammar above is not really LL(k) for any k, but we can build LL(1) grammar for the same language:

```
start -> statement // cannot change

statement -> IDENTIFIER statement0 SEMICOLON

statement0 ->  EQUAL expression

statement0 ->  LPAREN parameters RPAREN SEMICOLON
```

Of course, in the problem description, we do not see the definition of expression and parameters, so we assume we can build for them LL(1) rules as well (which is not guaranteed until we see the rules).